# .NET Core SQLite 'database is locked' only on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, sqlite, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I have a question, I have a small program that retrieves a CSV file and transforms it into a Sqlite database. On Windows no problem it works very well. On Linux, however, I get an error message:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=" + PathFile + targetFile;
using (SqliteConnection m_dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
{
    m_dbConnection.Open();
    // Requêtes de création des tables
    string sql = String.Empty;
    sql = String.Concat(sql, "CREATE TABLE TARGETS (idTarget NUMERIC, customerId NUMERIC, numberCard TEXT, mail TEXT, mobile TEXT, bat NUMERIC);");
    sql = String.Concat(sql, "CREATE TABLE COLUMNS (idColumn  NUMERIC, name TEXT, isVariable NUMERIC);");
    sql = String.Concat(sql, "CREATE TABLE ROW (idTarget  NUMERIC, idColumn TEXT, value TEXT);");
    // Execution des requêtes de création
    using (SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection))
    {
         countRow += command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <===== /!\ Exception here
    }
}
```

`Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 5: 'database is locked'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Mailing.Service.ServiceFile.ConvertCSVToSQLite(String sourceFile, String targetFile)
   at Mailing.Service.ServiceFile.UploadFile(Byte[] byteFile, String filename, TypeCanal canal, Int32 idMailing, Boolean async)
   at MailingAutomator.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 64`

Is there something different between Linux and Windows for Microsoft.Data.Sqlite?
A connection with the fact that on Linux I read and write on a mounted NAS ? A problem of access ? The sqlite database is created but empty.

.NET Core 2.2
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
Ubuntu 16.04

Edit : Some news :
When I use a samba share on a other ubuntu server it's works
But on other Windows share I get again this error... a journal file appears and disappears several times.
I don't understand, the sqlite file is created but empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem with my code.
I solved my issue by add "nobrl" to my mount command and it's works.

```
nobrl : Do not send byte range lock requests to the server. This is necessary for certain applications that break with cifs style mandatory byte range locks (and most cifs servers do not yet support requesting advisory byte range locks).
```